# Kohana, how to get the result of $query->execute()

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

```
    $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, "select * from users where username like :username") ;
    $query->param(':username', $username) ;
    $query->parameters(array(
        ':username' => '%'. $username. '%'
    )) ;

    $result = $query->execute()->as_array() ;

    if ($result->count() > 0)
    {
        return $result ;
    }
    else
    {
        return null ;
    }
```

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function count() on a non-object

how to get the result of query?anybody help ..thx..

Comment: Did you try `if (count($result) > 0)`?

Answer (score 2):

If `$result = $query->execute()->as_array() ;` returns an array, your if statement should be

```
if (count($result) > 0)
{
    return $result ;
}
else
{
    return null ;
}
```

Comment: `$result->count()`  means invoke the count method of the `$result` object, but in your case $result is an array, not an object with a count method.